# Disabling sequential transitions of child elements' inherited properties

Tags: css, css-transitions

Looking at this example:

http://jsbin.com/teqifogime/edit?html,css,output

In the first block, the text color changes alongside the transition of the background color because it's inheriting it from its parent.

The text color in the second block transitions only after its parent element has finished transforming.

This can be frustrating when putting together something that uses a lot of transitions, and seems like unexpected behavior. Any way around this?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="block block-one">
    <h2>Color Test</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="block block-two">
    <h2>Color Again</h2>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.block {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

h2 {
  transition: 1s;
}

.block-one:hover {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.block-one:hover h2 {
  color: azure;
}

.block-two:hover {
  color: azure;
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

*Edit*

For some clarity: in my real-world scenario I have a bunch of CSS components with their own transition properties, and some of them end up 'chaining' in this weird way. I end up needing to make a bunch of specific rules & exceptions to get what I would feel should be default behavior. Maybe my question is more about the nature of CSS - if there is some reason why things are working this way

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking, but I think removing the `transition` from `.block-two`'s `h2` should do the trick.

You have some options:

## 1st

```
.block-one h2 {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

## 2nd

```
.block-two h2 {
  transition: 0s;
}
```

## 3rd

```
.block-two-title {
  transition: 0s;
}
```

## 4th

```
.block-title--transition {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

Here's the **2nd** one:

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

h2 {
  transition: 1s;
}

.block-one:hover {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.block-one:hover h2 {
  color: azure;
}

.block-two:hover {
  color: azure;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.block-two h2 {
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block-one">
  <h2 class="block-title--animated">Color Test</h2>
</div>
<div class="block block-two">
  <h2>Color Again</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that does do the trick, but in my real-world scenario I have a bunch of CSS components with their own `transition` properties, and some of them end up 'chaining' in this weird way and I need to make a bunch of specific rules / exceptions to get what I would feel is default behavior. (Adding this explanation in an edit to my question)